# Date range filter in linq to crm

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm

I am using LINQ to query CRM entity. Below is my code

```
var data = svcContext.CreateQuery("myentity");
 if (info.FromDate != null && info.ToDate != null)
 {
    data = data.Where(r => r.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("rundate") >= info.FromDate.Value.Date && r.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("rundate") <= info.ToDate.Value.Date);
 }
```

This returns all records between FromDate and ToDate but it also consider time part while comparing which return wrong records. I want to truncate time part and use only date part for comparing. I already used code like this

**1.**

```
 if (info.FromDate != null && info.ToDate != null)
 {
    data = data.Where(r => r.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("rundate").Date >= info.FromDate.Value.Date && r.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("rundate").Date <= info.ToDate.Value.Date);
 }
```

**2.**

```
 if (info.FromDate != null && info.ToDate != null)
 {
    data = data.Where(r => Convert.ToDateTime(r.Attributes["rundate"]).Date >= info.FromDate.Value.Date && Convert.ToDateTime(r.Attributes["rundate"]).Date <= info.ToDate.Value.Date);
 }
```

**3.**

```
 if (info.FromDate != null && info.ToDate != null)
 {
    data = data.Where(r => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(r.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("rundate")) >= info.FromDate.Value.Date && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(r.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("rundate")).Date <= info.ToDate.Value.Date);
 }
```

These all returns **"Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method."** error. So how to compare by only date part and truncate time part. Thank you..

Comment: Simply do ToList after first query (which will return filtered records but with time considered). Next run your query without time on the result (it will be Linq to objects, so everything is supported)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the actual times do not matter, why don't you query your records by

```
var data = svcContext.CreateQuery("myentity");
if (info.FromDate != null && info.ToDate != null)
{
    var compareFromDate = info.FromDate.Value.Date;
    var compareToDate = info.ToDate.Value.Date.AddDays(1);
    data = data.Where(r => r.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("rundate") >= compareFromDate && r.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("rundate") < compareToDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CRM LINQ provider has some limitations that LINQ to Objects does not.

Adding ToList() to the CreateQuery result converts to using LINQ to Objects, which should allow you to do what you want.

For the comparisons you're looking to do, coverting to OLE Automation's decimal date format (OADate), then casting to int gives you a serial number for the date without any time component.

And, for clarity I moved the predicate to a separate method.

```
public override void Run()
{
    using (var context = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext(svc))
    {
        var result = (from e in context.CreateQuery("account").ToList()
                        .Where(ne => isBetween(ne.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("createdon"), DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.Now))
                        select e).ToList();     
    }
}

private bool isBetween(DateTime value, DateTime min, DateTime max)
{
    var val = (int)value.ToOADate();
    return val >= (int)min.ToOADate() || val <= (int)max.ToOADate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Aron but I can't use context.CreateQuery("account").ToList() because my entity already have nearly 5000 records and it keeps increasing. If I call .ToList() it will load all records in memory and then filters which I don't want from performance point of view. I tried to use your solution without .ToList() it returns same error as "Invalid 'where' condition......"